# Rhino Mock: FailedRecorded expectation: IDateHelper.get_Now();

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I was debugging this nondescript Rhino Mocks error:

> Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException: ... Expected #0,
>   Actual #1.

Found that putting `RhinoMocks.Logger = new TextWriterExpectationLogger(Console.Out);` before the recording gave me more info:

> FailedRecorded expectation: IDateHelper.get_Now();

But I have no idea how to fix this or even what is wrong.

Code looks like this:

```
IDateHelper dateHelper = mock.StrictMock<IDateHelper>();
DateTime now = new DateTime(2011, 12, 16);
Expect.Call(dateHelper.Now).Return(now).Repeat.Any();
...
public interface IDateHelper
    {
        DateTime Now { get; } 
    }
```

EDIT: Added the code that ledbutter asked for. I left out that dateHelper is being passed to another object, which is being passed to another object... I just didn't want to overwhelm you guys :) The code base I'm working with is huge and complex, and I didn't write it ;p

```
public IDateHelper DateHelper
    {
        get { return dateHelper ?? (dateHelper = new DateHelper()); }
        set { dateHelper = value; }
    }
...
string date = Helper.ConvertDateToYearMonth(DateHelper.Now.AddMonths(1));
```

The ExpectationViolationException happens a few lines after this when the date variable gets passed to another function.

Comment: So the method you are testing should be calling `IDateHelper.Now`, can you show that code?

Comment: Updated the question with the code. Thanks for looking at my question :)

Comment: Thanks, but can you show all the relevant lines in your unit test too?

Comment: Why aren't you using this syntax: `dateHelper.Expect(d => d.Now).Return(now);`?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you.  I have to agree with @ledbutter, the .Expect notation is I think a lot easier to understand.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Rhino.Mocks;

namespace FluentConfigHelper.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class StackOverflowTest
    {
        private IDateHelper _dateHelper;

        public interface IDateHelper
        {
            DateTime Now { get; }
        }

        public class DateHelper : IDateHelper
        {
            public DateTime Now { get; set; }
        }

        public IDateHelper DateHelperLocal
        {
            get { return _dateHelper ?? (_dateHelper = new DateHelper()); }
            set { _dateHelper = value; }
        }

        public DateTime MethodUnderTest()
        {
            return DateHelperLocal.Now.AddMonths(1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void DateTimeTest()
        {
            IDateHelper dateHelper = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IDateHelper>();
            DateTime now = new DateTime(2011, 12, 16);
            dateHelper.Expect(x => x.Now).Return(now);
            DateHelperLocal = dateHelper;
            var result = MethodUnderTest();
            Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2012, 1, 16), result);
            dateHelper.VerifyAllExpectations();
        }
    }
}
```